# Deduplication work not as expected in reducer

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have one `PersonDto` object with overwriting `equals()` and `hashCode()` method.

The main code in the reducer:

```
Set<PersonDto> set = new HashSet()<>;
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   Record red= iterator.next();
   PersonDto dto = new PersonDto();
   dto.setName(red.getString("name"));
   dto.setAge(red.getBigInt("age"));
   set.add(dto);
}
for (PersonDto dto : set) {
   context.write(new Text(dto.getname()+","+dto.getAge()));
}
```

But the final file on HDFS shows that same records still exist.
What is wrong with the code? Should I use map key to deduplicate?

Comment: For more complete answers, you have to provide some extra information, like your `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation, the number of reducers, the map method (or the format of output key-value pairs from mappers), and some output and input examples. What was expected and what is the actual output? Until then, intuitively, you might have PersonDto's which are equal end up in different reducers, if your equals() method is not a function on the actual map output key, as Amit suggests.

Comment: OK.I got it .The reducer works as well,map key is person's name,records are mapped to one jvm reducers.The essential reason is that some person name should be trimed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than 1 reducer ? If yes then there is a probability that same Person object is available in multiple reducers. In such case since each reducer is executing on its own and writing to HDFS, you may end up with duplicate Person records in the final output.

Comment: Is it that records with the same key should be processed on one reducer?

Comment: It depends on your key, Are you using the same hashcode that you use to deduplicate as a key for your map-reduce application ?

Comment: Yes ,I think so .The key is building with string,so records with same key should be processed in one jvm reducer,right?

Comment: What is the size of the data that you are handling , if it is like Proof Of concept or something of lesser size and if you have an option of using one reducer, you can check if using one reducer solves your issue. If it behaves as per your expectation then you will have to look at how your person records are keyed in your map-reduce application.